# Creating a Error Message in a SQL stored Procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I'm supposed to create a procedure that accepts a job code as a parameter and lists the full name and hire date for all employees with that job code.  Display a message if the job code is invalid. Created the following stored procedure but am unclear where the IF statement will go to prompt user an incorrect number was used. Second, should I hard code the only acceptable parameters? So @job_num = 500, @job_num=501...etc.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE getEmpInfo (@job_num = 500
                            @job_num = 501
                            @job_num = 502
                            @job_num = 503) //these would go to 510

//IF @job_code is not between 500 & 510
    PRINT 'Incorrect Job Code. Please Enter another number.'

AS
BEGIN
    SELECT EMPLOYEE.EMP_LNAME, EMPLOYEE.EMP_FNAME, EMPLOYEE.EMP_HIREDATE, JOB.JOB_CODE
    FROM   JOB JOIN ON EMPLOYEE.JOB_CODE = JOB.JOB_CODE
    WHERE  JOB_CODE = @job_code
END
```

Apologies for beginner questions but it's been fun learning.

Comment: Ideally, you should put that logic in your application.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`RAISERROR`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178592.aspx) function if the passed parameters do not validate. Along with [`RETURN`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174998.aspx) key word. which will stop the execution there and exit the code. something like this....

```
CREATE PROCEDURE getEmpInfo 
@job_code INT 
AS
BEGIN
 SET NOCOUNT ON;

    IF (@job_code < 500 OR @job_code > 510)
     BEGIN
       RAISERROR('Incorrect Job Code. Please Enter another number.', 16,1)
       RETURN
     END

SELECT  EMPLOYEE.EMP_LNAME
      , EMPLOYEE.EMP_FNAME
      , EMPLOYEE.EMP_HIREDATE
      , JOB.JOB_CODE
FROM   JOB INNER JOIN  EMPLOYEE
ON     JOB.JOB_CODE  = EMPLOYEE.JOB_CODE
WHERE  JOB.JOB_CODE  = @job_code    --<-- guessing here you decide

END
```

Also [`read here for correct Sql Server JOINS Syntax`](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/04/13/sql-server-introduction-to-joins-basic-of-joins/), Your join syntax is also wrong.